# How to add 2 jpeg pictures from excel in the same cell of a table in word document?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to add few jpeg pictures (up to 6) from excel worksheet in a table (word document), but only one appears at the end. Each time I am adding a picture it goes over the previous one. Here a part of my code with the issue:

```
' Filling the table
For i = 1 To iNumChem
    ' Column 1
    wdTable.Rows(i + 1).Cells(1).Range.Text = Sheet1.Cells(a + 1 + 2 * i - 2, 5).Value
    ' Column 2
    wdTable.Rows(i + 1).Cells(2).Range.Text = Sheet1.Cells(a + 1 + 2 * i - 2, 31).Value
    ' Column 3
    For p = 0 To 5
        If Sheet1.Cells(a + 2 * i, 5 + 2 * p).Value <> 0 Then
            Sheet3.Shapes(Sheet1.Cells(a + 2 * i, 5 + 2 * p).Value).Copy
            wdTable.Rows(i + 1).Cells(3).Range.PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next p
    ' Column 4
Next i
```

I tried to work with the properties ParagraphFormat and Move, but it didn't help.
I usually find difficult to move "the cursor" to the right position to be able to add something, especially in this case with Pictures (not Shapes) to add side by side.

Any ideas/comments are welcome.

Note: Edited after comments as I mixed the terms shape and picture!
I am trying to take pictures from Excel and add them in the same cell of a table word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you paste the shape it won't be ***in*** the cell, it will be anchored to it but float above it. This is just the same as in Excel where the shape floats above the worksheet and hides the cells below it.

To have the shape in the table you'll need to set the wrap type to inline, otherwise the shapes will stack up on top of each other.

```
With wdTable.Rows(i + 1).Cells(3).Range
   .PasteSpecial
   .ShapeRange(1).WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapInline
End With
```

EDIT:

Pictures are pasted into Word as InlineShapes. They do not stack up one on top of the other. If you attempt to paste more than one into `wdTable.Rows(i + 1).Cells(3).Range` each one will overwrite the last. Instead you need to declare a variable outside the loop, something like `wdCellRange as Word.Range`, and then use it when inserting the pictures, e.g.

```
Set wdCellRange = wdTable.Rows(i + 1).Cells(3).Range
With wdCellRange
    .Collapse Direction:= wdCollapseEnd
    .PasteSpecial
End With
```

Comment: Error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument. The picture I try to copy from excel to word is an imported picture (jpeg picture), if this information can help. I have seen online that others are using InlineShapes(1) and ConvertToShape, but I don't understand yet if that will help. Thanks for helping again anyway.

Comment: @JLuc01 - you need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64582886/edit) as you are pasting pictures ***not*** shapes. That is an important difference as Word handles pasting pictures differently. You also need to be clearer about what you are trying to achieve because your code is written to paste only one item per cell.

Comment: Sorry for mixing these words shape and picture! I corrected my question.

Comment: @JLuc01 - you haven't addressed the second point. Are you trying to put more than one picture in the same cell?

Comment: Yes, I just did it in my last note. Sorry again for mixing picture and shape.

Comment: @JLuc01 - please see edited answer. I cannot give you a completely worked answer as the code in your question is is incomplete and not reproducible.

Comment: Thanks again Timothy. It is working as I wanted now. The only weird point is I have to use Cells(2) to put it in column 3, but the principle is there. I should be able to sort out this little issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
...Range.Collapse Direction:= wdCollapseEnd
```

Comment: No error message, but it doesn't work. Thanks anyway.